# Using CTE table as a list in another table fails

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a CTE that executes and generates `top(100)` string id, based on some condition.

When I try to join it back with the original table to get the result, the query is getting stuck and does not generate output.

```
with sls as 
(
    Some table joins
),
topEntity as 
(
    SELECT TOP 100
        combined_ship2_id,
        SUM(price) AS slsamount
    FROM
        sls
    GROUP BY
        combined_ship2_id
)
SELECT
    customer_id, 
    customer_name,
    combined_ship2_id,
    year_for_period,
    SUM(extended_price) AS total_sls
​FROM
    sls
WHERE  
    combined_ship2_id IN (SELECT combined_ship2_id FROM topEntity)
GROUP BY
    customer_id,
    customer_name,
    combined_ship2_id,
    year_for_period
```

Both `sls` and `topEntity` are CTEs. I am able to get this query to execute if I replace

```
(SELECT combined_ship2_id FROM topEntity)
```

with

```
('id1', 'id2',....., 'id100')
```

which is the output of `topEntity` CTE.

I cant seem to find why

```
SELECT combined_ship2_id FROM topEntity
```

does not generate the desired result. Normal execution time of query is around 10 seconds. I kept it running for 10 minutes and still got no results.

Comment: Note that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: There is an order by in the query, i just removed that since i didnt keep the relavent column in the query.

Comment: We'd need to see the execution plan - but you might just want to materialise `topEntity` into a `#temp` table and reference that instead and see if that gives a better plan

Comment: @MartinSmith How can I upload the SQL plan?

Comment: you can use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: I presume probably the estimated number of rows coming out of this join is way off and it runs the subtree on the inside of the nested loops (including your `TOP` query) a lot more than it imagines it will https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLBDf.png - there are cardinality estimator warnings which may or may not be related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant seem to find why "select combined_ship2_id from topEntity" does not generate result.

The lexical order of your CTEs does not instruct SQL Server how to execute your query.  Having lots of CTEs is like writing a query on top of multiple levels of views:  not a bad thing per-se, but it makes the query optimizer's job harder.  And hard optimization jobs increases the risk of bad plans.

So, in general, when you have a long pipeline of CTEs and are experiencing poor query performance, consider materializing some intermediate stages of the pipeline into temp tables.

eg

```
with sls as (
Some table joins
),
topEntity as (
SELECT top 100
    combined_ship2_id
    ,sum(price) as slsamount
from sls
group by combined_ship2_id
order by slsamount desc
)
select *
into #topEntity 
from topEntity;

with sls as (
Some table joins
)
SELECT
    customer_id, 
    customer_name,
    combined_ship2_id,
    year_for_period,
    sum(extended_price) as total_sls
​
from
    sls
WHERE  
    combined_ship2_id in (select combined_ship2_id from #topEntity)
GROUP  BY
    customer_id,
    customer_name,
    combined_ship2_id,
    year_for_period
```

Comment: I was not able to identify the original cause of the issue but this temp table solution helped me solve the problem. Thank you